# Is there a way to store Visual Paradigm .bak and .vux files in a sub directory

Tags: visual-paradigm

I have been working with Visual Paradigm for a while not and I love the tool. The only thing I get annoyed by is the amount of files it generates for each project.

The files I mean are `<project name>.vpp.bak_<number>` and `<project name>.vux`.

Is there a way to store them somewhere else (like a subdirectory) or delete them automatically?

Comment: I was hoping this would have an answer. Have you manage to do it?